# Feynman Diagrams using Spin Connections

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, feynman-diagrams

The spin connection $\omega_{\mu}^{ab}$ can be considered to be the gauge field which is generated by local Lorentz transformations.  Since it is a gauge field, is there some framework where one could analyse terms in a gravitational Lagrangian which use the spin connection by some suitable Feynman rules?

So, for example, a term like with a product of three spin connections would be considered as a trilinear vertex for that gauge field?